# TypeError: "Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 519 has value 8230 which is greater than 255."

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, api, axios

I'm currently working in laravel and react js. I've made api end points in laravel for login registration with laravel passport. Now, I've made following route to get user details when api_token is provided.

**Route**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
    Route::post('details', 'API\UserController@details');
});
```

Here is controller,

**Controller**

```
/** 
 * details api 
 * 
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response 
 */ 
public function details() 
{ 
    $user = Auth::user(); 
    return response()->json(['success' => $user], $this->successStatus); 
}
```

**React**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Home extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(
            '127.0.0.1:8000/api/details/',
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6ImNmMTkxMjQ0ZWVhZmJlZjNmMDljM2ExMDc0MzgwZjE2ZGY2MGY3YTAwOGI0ZmQyZjY4OTI2NWJiZWJlNGIzNTU0ZDNhZGM1ZDNhOTk2ODgzIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIzIiwianRpIjoiY2YxOTEyNDRlZWFmYmVmM2YwOWMzYTEwNzQzODBmMTZkZjYwZjdhMDA4YjRmZDJmNjg5MjY1YmJlYmU0YjM1NTRkM2FkYzVkM2E5OTY4ODMiLCJpYXQiOjE1NDU1ODQ4ODYsIm5iZiI6MTU0NTU4NDg4NiwiZXhwIjoxNTc3MTIwODg2LCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.rRgHTChM8n-3r6syYaH9t0KKQLYLki9_jAsg6UUtX5Y3KUznr8IuAQnPKpuy-6jirEtjB6lG5GA6z7vHonp0YH-dWR3VxRfw_69vf6DfV0Z1yVzqitz7h-zsbC4j…BT_roRITEVusZWogUcpgMrvZs-jbVpfb6DpfNE0RA9ID2t_LSK9wlIc7_LeZFgqwPhBr90aUjpWQNnAfPg8l_DiWWAZLWoSRlYswQ9pQkIwyI-QYfTfIXxAKDdnOTLn7u4cLx1a_lj0IrIudlLPAPI3gqeJWzYYD8e3y7TuQtUv3zvb7rzW-AT6dV2RQO-bzd4OZDraRzrRbhc1qmYy1v0o0FkRxKgIagx69iIjwEyH7wwG08tq9OSptRtviGKZk1cu5T9qywDc4fA61_3lEPPACh_hUgdUc7qOnaKk3mU8nfnonSA0NQzfV_nK9PvGG_NzUQVk4Gei3YEqsUBl-JgofIEO310OBL9cgfa7cFjPMaw90o6XcP9c3abZZFHWGhVJPSrzyLidr_rC2RVhX5M7UvNDxS5Rw-bOWpQiYhd69_-Jk3B92gFWbLk4IBRqkaxGhEmV7netaTkFDF_e0f-R7HjUhicDJe6HQKCBFqzsAwSyax7NoFquWxZeJ4EA',
                    'Accept':'application/json'
                }
            }
        ).then(response => {
            this.setState({
                    name: response.success.name,
                    email: response.success.email
                });
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error);

        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h4>Name: {this.state.name}</h4>
                <h4>Email: {this.state.email}</h4>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I send the request with api_token, I've got following error.

> TypeError: "Cannot convert string to ByteString because the character at index 519 has value 8230 which is greater than 255."
>
> setRequestHeader http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:876:11
>
> forEach http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2339:9
>
> dispatchXhrRequest http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:870:7
>
> xhrAdapter http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:762:10
>
> dispatchRequest http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1375:10

What I'm doing wrong any suggestion/help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add your response json

Comment: @AaminKhan I've not got json response, just got above error

Comment: Do you mean you didn't get any response back from `127.0.0.1:8000/api/details/`

Comment: @AaminKhan, when i send request from postman it works perfectly but the above error when i send request from axios. I'm sorry, I'm new to react js

Comment: Also it should be `response.data.success.name` - usually it is if you not modified the response structure form laravel

Comment: @AaminKhan still same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185690/discussion-between-aamin-khan-and-sagar-gautam).

Comment: @AaminKhan okay

Answer (score 23):

I encountered the same error and found out that it was due to the header string containing Unicode characters. In the above example, the Authorization header contains “…”.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because I had the same issue. The difference was only that my Authorization header had wrong double-ticks. The problem occured because the auth header was sent via Slack. And I guess that Slack is escaping the original straight " ones to the italic “ ones. @umitu thanks again!